# Why does icacls show different permissions for C: root directory depending on from which folder I run it?

Tags: windows, cmd, icacls

When I run `icacls` to check permissions for my `C:` root directory, the result differs depending on from which folder I run the command. Why is that?

Examples:

Running it from `C:`

```
C:\>icacls "C:"
C: BUILTIN\Administratörer:(OI)(CI)(F)
   NT instans\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
   BUILTIN\Användare:(OI)(CI)(RX)
   NT instans\Autentiserade användare:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
   NT instans\Autentiserade användare:(AD)
   Obligatorisk etikett\Hög obligatorisk nivå:(OI)(NP)(IO)(NW)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Running it from `C:\Users`:

```
C:\Users>icacls "C:"
C: NT instans\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
   BUILTIN\Administratörer:(OI)(CI)(F)
   BUILTIN\Användare:(RX)
   BUILTIN\Användare:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
   Alla:(RX)
   Alla:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Running it from `C:\Logs`:

```
C:\Logs>icacls "C:"
C: BUILTIN\Administratörer:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
   NT instans\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
   BUILTIN\Användare:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
   NT instans\Autentiserade användare:(I)(M)
   NT instans\Autentiserade användare:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

I would expect the permissions to be the same no matter from which folder I run the command.

Comment: You are doing different directories. `c:` is the default directory on C drive.

Comment: "C:" is a drive relative path, which is relative to the current working directory on the drive, which you keep changing here. The root directory on drive "C:" is "C:\".

Comment: Thank you @ErykSun , I managed to get it to work consistently once I added the backslash. "C:\" did not work with the quotes, while C:\ without the quotes worked, which threw me off. Thanks, could you add it as an answer and I'll mark it as answered?

Comment: `icacls "C:\"` should have been made to work, but it's simplistically parsing it as an escaped double quote and tries to open `C:"`. You have to double the backslash as `icacls "C:\\"`, or use a forward slash `icacls "C:/"`.